# Where are the StarCraft 2 replay videos stored and can I share them?

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I wanted to send a copy of a replay video to a friend of mine but cannot find the StarCraft 2 video folder.

Are these stored locally or on Battle.net?

Regardless of where they are stored how can I share these replay videos?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, they are in a directory such as:

```
C:\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\[number]\[other]\Replays
```

The cool thing is that the replay files themselves are quite small (11-15 KB on my computer) so it should be easy to email and share.  Another cool thing is that SC2 registers the ".SC2Replay" file extension, so all you need to do is double click on the file to play it - you (or your friend) don't even need to copy it into their own "Replays" directory.

Comment: The `My Documents` / `Documents` directory will vary based on version of windows. Other than that great answer especially the bit about file size and extension!

Comment: The "My Documents" folder is in `C:\Users\\[User]\Documents` (Windows Vista/Windows 7) or `C:\Documents and Settings\\[User]\My Documents` (Windows XP).  In all versions of Windows XP or later, you can simply type `%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts`

Comment: @BlueRaja: However, `~\My Documents` is symlinked to `~\Documents` in those versions that have `~\Documents`.

Answer (score 13):

On OS X as of patch 1.1:

`/Users/[You]/Library/Application Support/Blizzard`
`/StarCraft II/Accounts/[Account]/[Profile]/Replays`.

Before patch 1.1 the `StarCraft II` folder was located in `/Users/[You]/Documents` instead of under Application Support.

Unfortunately, while opening a `.sc2replay` file in OS X will launch the game, it won't auto-start the replay. You'll have to move it to your `Replays` folder and use the in-game UI to start it.

Answer (score 6):

Windows 7:

```
C:\Users\[USER]\Documents\StarCraft II\Accounts\[number]\[other]\Replays
```

Answer (score 3):

Check for a starcraft 2 folder in "My Documents"

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers about where they are physically located on your hard drive.  As for sharing there are a number of sites that let you upload your replay.
[SC2replayed](http://www.sc2replayed.com) is a good one.

You can upload your replay files there, the site will parse the replay data and provide helpful info about the replay and allow you to share it with friends.

[Example of a shared replay through sc2replayed.com](http://www.sc2replayed.com/replays/63404-1v1-terran-protoss-lost-temple)

Answer (score 2):

If I remember it right it was: MyDocuments\Starcraft2\Profiles\[Something]\Replays (I'll check that later)

You can send replay file to anyone who has Starcraft 2 and after they put it in their Replays folder they can watch it in game.

Comment: +1 if you're right, I'll check that later ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Just go to replays in the starcraft program and choose "show in Finder"

Answer (score 1):

Also you could just search for *.SC2Replay.