# What is in Blizzard's Cloud?

Tags: starcraft-2

When installing SC2 on a new computer, some things are preserved when you log into your old account.  I thought save games were one of them, but [apparently not](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108468/20818).

This naturally leads to the question, what IS stored in the cloud.  Achievements seem to be, but not campaign progess.  Are replays? Custom Maps? Friend list? Anything else?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Blizzard's [cloud service Battle.net](http://battle.net) stores a variety of StarCraft 2 information:

### Things stored in the cloud:

- Achievements / Feats of Strength
- Campaign Progress (but not save games)
- Friend List (across all Blizzard properties: Diablo, World of WarCraft, StarCraft)
- [Player Profile](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/343464/1/ahsteele/) (which provides a UI for much of the above)

### Not stored in the cloud:

- [replay videos](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/3830/559)
- save games
- unpublished custom maps

Comment: So when they mention playing at home and work without transferring saves here: http://blizzlive.com/content/starcraft-ii-battle-net-discussion-panel   did that just not happen?

Comment: @Kexlox I think they would argue that it did happen. I read the statement from the post as finished missions (i.e. campaign progress) and not in game saves.

Comment: Have a look at my linked question then, I'm not able to start a mission past the first one, even though I was headed to Char on my last install.

Comment: @Kexlox When I get home I'll walk through the screens so I can describe how to start play at specific campaign mission. Though if memory serves its more one off play than what your [linked question is after](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/108468/559).

Comment: @Kexlox I posted a definitive answer to your other question about save game storage. I am still going to attempt to answer the restart question when I get some time in front of my PC.

Comment: @Kexlox based on some of your other comments around the site I think you had your problem resolved, but I still went ahead and added screenshots to my answer to your other questions: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/108587/559.

Comment: What about custom hotkeys?